# Javascript canvas, collision detection via array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

Basically, I have a program that makes a square, and stores the left, right, top and bottoms in an array. When it makes a new square, it cycles through the array. If the AABB collision detection makes the new square overlap with another square, it should make sure that the square is not displayed, and tries again. Here is a snippet of the code I made, where I think the problem is:

```
var xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares = [];

//Makes a randint() function.
function randint(min, max) {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function checkForOccupiedAlready(left, top, right, bottom) {

    if (xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.length == 0) {

        return true;
    }
    for (i in xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares) {
        if (i[0] <= right || i[1] <= bottom ||
            i[2] >= left || i[3] >= top) {/*Do nothing*/} 
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//Makes a new square
function makeNewsquare() {
    var checkingIfRepeatCords = true;

    //DO loop that checks if there is a repeat.
    do {
        //Makes the square x/y positions 
        var squareRandomXPos = randint(50, canvas.width - 50);
        var squareRandomYPos = randint(50, canvas.height - 50);

        //Tests if that area is already occupied
        if (checkForOccupiedAlready(squareRandomXPos, 
                                    squareRandomYPos, 
                                    squareRandomXPos+50, 
                                    squareRandomYPos+50) == true) {

            xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.push([squareRandomXPos, 
                                            squareRandomYPos, 
                                            squareRandomXPos+50, 
                                            squareRandomYPos+50]);

            checkingIfRepeatCords = false;

        }
    }
    while (checkingIfRepeatCords == true);

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: use a `for loop`, not a `for in` :  `for (var i=0; i < xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.length; i++) {
var botSquare = xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares[i];
        if (botSquare[0] <= right || botSquare[1] <= bottom ||
            botSquare[2] >= left || botSquare[3] >= top) {/*Do nothing*/} 
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: you are confusing for...in with for...of. for...in iterates in the indexes, not the elements. for...of does iterate in the elements, but it's very poorly supported by browsers as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect I think, since you use `i` as a value, whereas it is a key:

```
for (i in xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares) {
    if (i[0] <= right || i[1] <= bottom ||
        i[2] >= left || i[3] >= top) {/*Do nothing*/} 
    else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Could become:

```
for (var i = 0, l < xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.length; i < l; i++) {
    var data = xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares[i];

    if (data[0] <= right || data[1] <= bottom ||
        data[2] >= left  || data[3] >= top) {/*Do nothing*/} 
    else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and I am sorry I could not get back to you! Ill check if that is correct!

Comment: I am so sorry, but this does not help. But thank you for trying! =D

Comment: No prob! Well it may not solve your problem, but I'm pretty sure it will not work with your question's code (because `i` is an index of `xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares` and not an actual value)